# Import CSV file from URL into SQL Fiddle Postgres 9.6 engine

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlfiddle

I am trying a whole day long to find a solution for importing csv file from url into SQL Fiddle, using the PostgreSQL 9.6. Nothing on the Internet helped. When I use the "Copy" command I get the following message:

[image]

When I try \copy I get error saying that "\" is error. With stdin/out I got something like saying that the engine doesn't support it. What is the real command or script for that. I am starting to lose patience. Please help!

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` command and only available if you use `psql` as your SQL client. `copy` reads the file **on the server** so it wouldn't be of any help with SQLFiddle. Why SQLFiddle doesn't support `copy from stdin` you need to ask the SQLFiddle developers. In a nutshell: you can't import a CSV file in SQLFiddle. You need to convert the file into a SQL script using INSERT statements

Comment: HI! Could you please tell me what the script of "copy from stdin" for a given url would be? I am not sure that I am writing it right. Many thanks in advance! I tried with INSERT Statements, but I get more than 8000 elements in the code which gives me error again.

Comment: `copy from stdin` doesn't work with URLs. If you need to insert 8000 rows, then write an INSERT with 8000 rows.

Comment: Or may be how can I make it with \copy? Many thanks once more!

Comment: As I wrote: `\copy` **only** works within `psql`

Comment: I wanted to make it with one line, but as it seems it is not that easy. OK.  Yes you are right. Only one insert and all the values will work. Thank you very much  a_horse_with_no_name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the file into a SQL script using INSERT statements